# Storage API + Services 3: How to work together?

Tags: 7, files, services

I am trying to set up a site that will be storing a large amount of images. I am using Storage API module for that and It is working fine through web.

Now I need a REST Service to upload images.
I am trying with the default file POST endpoint of the Services module:

```
--> POST http://example.com/api/file http/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 343901
Cookie: ..............
X-Csrf-Token: .........
{"file":"iVBOR.......Jggg==","filename":"myimage.png","uri":"storage-field-images://myimage.png"}
--> END POST (343901-byte body)



<-- 200 OK http://example.com/api/file (888ms)
Content-Type: application/json
{"fid":"81","uri":"http://example.com/api/file/81"}
<-- END HTTP (74-byte body)
```

But http://example.com/api/file/81 is responding me:

```
{"fid":"81","filename":"myimage.png","uri":"public://myimage.png".........
```

(Not the same uri that I sent in the request)

Am I missing something in the resquest? Or do I have to develop a new endpoint to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

replace `uri` with `filepath`

```
--> POST http://example.com/api/file http/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 343901
Cookie: ..............
X-Csrf-Token: .........
{"file":"iVBOR.......Jggg==","filename":"myimage.png","filepath":"public://storage-field-images/myimage.png"}
--> END POST (343901-byte body)
```